# Trying to navigate to a page from navbar gives Recycler View: No adapter attached; skipping layout error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with a navbar. However, when I try to navigate to another fragment using the navbar, it gives me the error: RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout and it does not navigate. However, the title of the page changes to the required fragment. Here is the java code:

```
package com.example.fresh24;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MachineCategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private RecyclerView machineCategoryRecyclerView;
    private MachineCategoryAdapter machineCategoryAdapter;


    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private static final int HOME_FRAGMENT = 0;
    private static final int CART_FRAGMENT = 1;
    private static final int ORDERS_FRAGMENT = 2;
    private static final int WISHLIST_FRAGMENT = 3;
    private static final int REWARDS_FRAGMENT = 4;
    private static final int ACCOUNT_FRAGMENT = 5;
    public static Boolean showCart = false;

    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    private int currentFragment = -1;

    private Window window;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    //Added by Prashant


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_machine_category);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


        machineCategoryRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.other_category_machine_recyclerview);


        window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_machine_category_child);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view_machine_category);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);

        frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_framelayout);
        if (showCart) {
            drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            gotoFragment("My Cart", new MyCartFragment(), -2);
        } else {
            //This is the hamburger icon
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();
            // This is the hamburger
            setFragment(new HomeFragment(), HOME_FRAGMENT);
        }



        //Horizontal Product Layout

        String left = "left";
        List<HorizontalProductScrollModel> horizontalProductScrollModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        horizontalProductScrollModelList.add(new HorizontalProductScrollModel("101", R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark, "Product 1", "7\n" + left, "₹530"));
        horizontalProductScrollModelList.add(new HorizontalProductScrollModel("102", R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark, "Product 2", "8\n" + left, "₹531"));
        horizontalProductScrollModelList.add(new HorizontalProductScrollModel("103", R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark, "Product 3", "9\n" + left, "₹532"));
        horizontalProductScrollModelList.add(new HorizontalProductScrollModel("104", R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark, "Product 4", "10\n" + left, "₹533"));
        horizontalProductScrollModelList.add(new HorizontalProductScrollModel("104", R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark, "Product 5", "10\n" + left, "₹533"));
        horizontalProductScrollModelList.add(new HorizontalProductScrollModel("105", R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark, "Product 6", "10\n" + left, "₹533"));


        //Horizontal Product Layout

        ///////Recyclerview Testing

        LinearLayoutManager testingLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        testingLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        machineCategoryRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(testingLayoutManager);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////
        List<HomePageModel> homePageModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        homePageModelList.add(new HomePageModel(0, "Tray 1", horizontalProductScrollModelList));
        homePageModelList.add(new HomePageModel(0, "Tray 2", horizontalProductScrollModelList));
        homePageModelList.add(new HomePageModel(0, "Tray 3", horizontalProductScrollModelList));
        homePageModelList.add(new HomePageModel(0, "Tray 5", horizontalProductScrollModelList));
        homePageModelList.add(new HomePageModel(0, "Tray 6", horizontalProductScrollModelList));
        homePageModelList.add(new HomePageModel(0, "Tray 7", horizontalProductScrollModelList));
        homePageModelList.add(new HomePageModel(0, "Tray 8", horizontalProductScrollModelList));

        HomePageAdapter adapter = new HomePageAdapter(homePageModelList);
        machineCategoryRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.main_search_icon) {
            //todo: search
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.main_notification_icon) {
            //todo:notification system
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.main_cart_icon) {
            //todo:cart
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.nav_fresh24) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            setFragment(new HomeFragment(), HOME_FRAGMENT);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_orders) {
            gotoFragment("My Orders", new MyOrdersFragment(), ORDERS_FRAGMENT);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_rewards) {
            gotoFragment("My Rewards", new MyRewardsFragment(), REWARDS_FRAGMENT);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_cart) {
            gotoFragment("My Cart", new MyCartFragment(), CART_FRAGMENT);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_wishlist) {
            gotoFragment("My Wishlist", new MyWishlistFragment(), WISHLIST_FRAGMENT);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_account) {
            gotoFragment("My Account", new MyAccountFragment(), ACCOUNT_FRAGMENT);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sign_out) {

        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_machine_category_child);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    private void gotoFragment(String title, Fragment fragment, int fragmentNo) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        setFragment(fragment, fragmentNo);
        if (fragmentNo == CART_FRAGMENT) {
            navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setChecked(true);
        }

    }

    private void setFragment(Fragment fragment, int fragmentNo) {
        if (fragmentNo != currentFragment) {
            if (fragmentNo == REWARDS_FRAGMENT) {
                window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#5B04B1"));
                toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5B04B1"));
            } else {
                window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            }
            currentFragment = fragmentNo;
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(frameLayout.getId(), fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }


}
```

I have tried looking around for solution but could not solve the issue. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like you are not setting the adapter when you open a new fragment. You need to call setAdapter() method inside your fragment.java code too. For example if your MyOrdersFragment() contains recyclerView and you want to inflate it when you open that fragment then you need to call setAdapter() method inside MyOrdersFragment().